# How can I save all session information of Webview tabs using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, webview, local-storage, indexeddb

I am planning a mobile application that will enable users to log in easily, although some applications' login information is saved very easily, unfortunately not all of them are.

[flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) Using this package I can save users' localStorage and cookies, but for a specific application I need to save data in IndexedDB as well. I set this data again every time the browser starts. Is there a feature where I can save the complete browser information or is there a way to save IndexedDB?